# Solucionar: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

tengo el siguiente modulo js que recibe datos de una formulario y los envia a los datos una funcion en un controlador:

```
export const updateBranch = ({ }, payload) => {
    console.log ("El id es " + payload.id + ", El hexa es " + payload.form.color.hexa)
    return axios.patch(window.urls.branch.update(payload.id), payload.form)
        .then(response => {
            return Promise.resolve()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject(error)
        })
}
```

esto tengo en mi config.blade.php, con las rutas de branch y el update que deberia llamar el modulo js:

```
window.urls = {
    auth : {
        login : 'auth/login',
        fetchUser: 'auth/me',
        logout : 'auth/logout',
        updatePassword : 'auth/password',
        updatePersonalData : 'auth/me',
        updateEmail : 'auth/email',
    },
    branch: {
        index : '/branch',
        store: '/branch',
        update: function(branchid){
            return '/branch/' + branchid + 'update'
        }

    },
```

esta es la ruta que utilizo:

```
Route::patch('/{branch}/update', [
            'uses' => 'BranchController@update',
            'middleware' => 'permission:branch.update'
        ]);
```

esta es la funcion del controlador:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($id);
        $color=$request->input('color.hexa');
        $branch=Branch::find($id);
        $branch->name= $request->name;
        $branch->color= $color;
        $branch->save();

        return $branch;
    }
```

Comment: Abre el log de Laravel y añade que error se está generando

Comment: no aparece nada en el storage/logs, no tengo ningun archivo desde hace 2 dias tengo registro solo hasta el dia 5/11 hoy es 7/11 no me aparece nada

Comment: Como menciona @Aprendiz, es dificil saberlo sin ver cual es el log de Laravel. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` es un mensaje genérico. De todas maneras, aún sin esa info, en el código da para ver que la url que le pasas a axios no coincide con la uri de la ruta de Laravel

Comment: mira ahi le agrego lo que creo que falta a la consulta, ya la corrijo

Comment: ahi lo correji, espero que sea eso

Comment: Para `Route::patch('/{branch}/update', ...`, la url que le pasas a axios debería ser `'/' + branchid + '/update'`